# Change Function from getActiveSheet() to getSheetByName("mySheet")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am very new to Google scripts and am finding it a little confusing

The function `getdata` along with setting a timer will re-query the `ImportJSON` but the function only writes to the first sheet.

I need to set which sheet the function writes to.

I have tried:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("mySheet").getRange('A2').setValue(cellFunction);
```

but does not work.

Thanks!

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();
  var cellFunction = '=ImportJSON("https://sum-app.net/json?key=Mg.Clxt6A.TV1DFtPA0k8Ehpb0RDxyLH7xhU8", "/elements", "noInherit,noTruncate,Headers?' + "," + queryString + '")';

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue(cellFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt, `getActiveSpreadsheet` should be `getActiveSpreadsheet()`